# VPN - India to US performance

Tags: vpn

Is there a way to get VPN performance from India to USA to be consistent with the performance from USA to USA or will network performance from India to USA always be behind no matter what steps are taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always be behind. See, VPN uses the internet. The internet uses electicity and optical signals. Per definition there is this funny thing called speed of light.

Basically, US to US is a lot less distance, so signals travel in a lot less time. Simple like that.

Comment: Hah.  Perfect.  That was what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: Not sure that I understand the speed of light reference. I suspect the delays caused by all the connecting store-and-forward network equipment (routers/switches) have a far large impact then the ~0.08s added because of the time it takes light to travel 25,000km.  If he could afford a point-to-point fiber connection between India and somewhere in the US, I am sure he could nice speedy connections.  I suspect the cost for a point-to-point fiber would be in the hundreds of millions of dollars though.

Comment: Latency is not everything, and there are ways to make the most of a high-bandwidth, high-latency link. But you are right, leave no chance unused to complain about the slowness of light.

Comment: @Zoredache: you'd be surprised. Light is s - l - o - w. Both astronomers and WAN-technicians know. Edit: gamers are like tiny wantechs.

Comment: @Zore - I understand. Basically if you had an direct network connection running from the east coast to the west coast of the US (with a more powerful optical transciever than I've ever heard of), it would still be slower than the same network from india to the US - even under the best, most optimal, expensive network in the world. All the other issues that exist in a connection of that size exacerbate the issue.

Comment: That isn't what I am trying to say.  I am trying to suggest that in the real world the dozen, or more, network devices that you probably have to pass though to get from India to the US have a far bigger impact on the transmission time then the delay caused by the copper/glass medium.  The distance does matter from the perceptive that the longer the run the more likely there will be more devices between the two points that will add delay.

Answer (score 1):

In reality India seems to have quite poor external and internal internet connectivity - hops and connection speed and the reliability of each hop/network is the issue IMO much more than the simple fact of distance.